# Передать значение в форму

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

Есть страница категории товаров.
У каждого есть ID - product ['id'], название - product['name'], цена -
 product['price'].
У каждого товара есть кнопка `<button class="opener"> </button>`

Есть html форма, в которую нужно передать название товара и его цену.

Есть скрипт на jquery - использующий какую-то стандартную библиотеку "dialog", который скрывает форму до момента нажатия на кнопку и открывает после нажатия.

Задача: при нажатии на кнопку открывается форма во всплывающем окне, и  в соответствующие поля формы записываются значения цены и названия.

Привожу код(с купюрами для экономии места):

Продукт:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
<div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
  <div class="price"> 

        <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
        <span class="regprice"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
<button class="opener">Кнопка</button>
```

Jquery:

```
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script> 
  $( function() {
      $( "#form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 500,
      title: "Форма",
      closeText: "",
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 500
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 500
      }
    }); 

   }


    $( ".opener" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( "#form" ).dialog( "open");
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

Форма:

```
<div id="form">
<form action="http://example.com/action.php" method="post">
<input name="itemName" value="##здесь должно быть имя товара##" type="hidden"/>
<input name="itemQuantity" value="1" type="hidden"/>
<input name="itemPrice" value="##Здесь должна быть цена товара##" type="hidden"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае нужно руками проставить значения при отркытии окна, используй селектор по имени, вот [пример](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

```
$( ".opener" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( "input[name='itemName']" ).val( "Твое наименование" );
  $( "input[name='itemPrice']" ).val( "Твоя цена" );
  $( "#form" ).dialog( "open");
});
```

Но лучше испольвать поиск не по имени, а по [классу](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) или [ID](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

```
<input class="itemName" type="hidden"/>
```

Или

```
<input id="itemName" type="hidden"/>
```

Comment: Проблема в том откуда взять эту .val( "Твое наименование" ). Ведь товаров то на странице много. Я сейчас временно добавил в каждый товар и форму и jquery с открывашкой и поставит классам формы и кнопки id товара, примерно так :class="opener<?php echo product['id'];?>" Но как по мне не очень изящное решение плодить 50 скрытых форм на странице и 50 идентичных скриптов

Comment: Понял.
Записывай значения прямо в твой элемент в data атрибут.

Comment: Может я что-то не понял в ответе или вопрос не совсем полно задал. Нужно, чтобы форма и скрипт были в единичном экземпляре на странице. А при клике на кнопку конкретного товара в форму подставлялись значения именно этого товараю

Comment: Могу я попросить поподробнее объяснить, если не трудно.

Answer (score 0):

При отрисовке всех элементов сохраняй их необходимые значения в data атрибуты, вот [документация](http://htmlbook.ru/samouchitel-html5/atributy-data) и [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

```
<div class="item" data_name="Записываем имя" data_price="Записываем стоимтость"/>
```

А в при нажатии кнопки забирай значения из текущего элемента c помощью js.

```
$(".item").click(function(){
   var name = $(this).data("name");
   var price = $(this).data("price");
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Присвоил кнопке атрибуты data с ценой и названием. В скрипте всплывашки к ним обращаюсь и подставляю в форму, как ты показал ранее. Вроде бы все корректно работает.